# How are options used to avoid capital gains taxes on shares?

Tags: options, capital-gains-tax, investment-income

This question is based on this quote from another online resource. I had been reading about  common methods of tax avoidance for the super wealthy, and this one didn't make sense to me.

> One cunning way of dodging capital gains tax is by borrowing from an
>   investment bank with the shares as collateral after purchasing
>   options, which set their price at a fixed rate.
>
> This sneaky option allows the borrower to avoid triggering the capital
>   gains tax that would come with actually having the money at hand,
>   while giving them the free cash – and allowing them to repay the loan
>   – either from the profits of using the money or by handing over the
>   shares themselves. Talk about making your money work for you.

I don't really follow this strategy, and I would appreciate someone walking through a fictional example to illustrate how it works.

Here's as far as I understand it, using made-up numbers: you borrow $10 million, using $10 million in stock as collateral which you give(?) to an investment bank like Goldman Sachs.....but then I got confused when it said "after purchasing options." (I know what options are, I trade them; the issue is not that I don't understand what they are. Only that I don't understand the strategy here.)

Then the next paragraph really ratcheted up my confusion. You're repaying the loan with the cash you got from the loan? What? I've totally lost what they're saying.

What exactly is the sequence of actions here, and how do they benefit the wealthy individual who's doing it?

Comment: Can you provide the source?  It's hard to fabricate an answer based on your interpretation of insufficient information. EDIT:  Never mind.  I found it with a Google search.  AFAIC, those two paragraphs are a lot of words that in effect say nothing at all.

Comment: I've found it mentioned in a number of places though. [Here's](https://www.moneytips.com/how-the-mega-rich-avoid-paying-taxes) another source explaining the same thing in a different way, but still unclear: "One example is to purchase stock options at a fixed rate, then use those options as collateral to borrow money, which is used to make money off other opportunities. The loan is then paid off with those proceeds or by handing over the shares, thus avoiding capital gains."

Comment: I suspect that this involves OTC optio s b/t the invextor and a counterparty or the investor and the investment bank, hedge fund, whatever..  The rules are different for those (not subject to SEC margin rules, etc.).  The problem with both explanations is twofold.  If  there's borrowing, there must be a borrow cost. But of greater importance, you still have to invest that borrowed  money wisely and make money.  If you don't, you lose some portion, even all of the collateral.  There's no free lunch.  And per IRS regs, regardless of the source, cap gains are taxable.  I don't see this.